# Differences and relation between host and server in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In the `Program.cs` of an ASP.net Core project, we could use `IWebHostBuilder` to create(or build) an `IWebHost` which, I think, is a host.

When creating an `IWebHost`, we could specify the web server which is `Kestrel` or `HttpSys` by using the extension method `UseKestrel` or `UseHttpSys` accordingly.

So my question is what the differences and relation between host and web server here in ASP.net Core.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reviewing the ASP.NET Core [fundamentals page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) which includes the following definitions. I feel the section in italics in the server definition aptly describes the relationship between host and server.

> **Hosting**
>
> ASP.NET Core apps configure and launch a host, which is
> responsible for app startup and lifetime management.
>
> For more information, see [Host in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/index?view=aspnetcore-2.0).
>
> **Servers**
>
> *The ASP.NET Core hosting model doesn't directly listen for
> requests. The hosting model relies on an HTTP server implementation to
> forward the request to the app.* The forwarded request is wrapped as a
> set of feature objects that can be accessed through interfaces.
> ASP.NET Core includes a managed, cross-platform web server, called
> Kestrel. Kestrel is often run behind a production web server, such as
> IIS or Nginx. Kestrel can be run as an edge server.
>
> For more information, see [Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/index?view=aspnetcore-2.0) and the following topics:
>
> [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
>
> [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
>
> [HTTP.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.0) (formerly called [WebListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/weblistener?view=aspnetcore-2.0))